# Texture Wrapping isn't being applied properly

Tags: opengl, c++

I've debugged my application with codeXL and can verify that my texture is getting these attributes applied:

```
GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER: GL_LINEAR
GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER: GL_LINEAR
GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S: GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T: GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R: GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
```

With the following UV data:

```
0, 0,
1, 0,
1, 1,
1, 1,
0, 1,
0, 0,
0, 0,
1, 0,
1, 1,
1, 1,
0, 1,
0, 0,
0, 1,
0, 1,
0, 0,
0, 0,
0, 0,
0, 1,
1, 1,
1, 1,
1, 0,
1, 0,
1, 0,
1, 1,
0, 0,
1, 0,
1, 0,
1, 0,
0, 0,
0, 0,
0, 1,
1, 1,
1, 1,
1, 1,
0, 1,
0, 1
```

Yet my cube still looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FARE.jpg

The Front and Back are being mapped fine, but the sides and top/bot are all stretched. I've tried with `GL_REPEAT`, `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE/BORDER`, `GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT`, it's all the same result. I've tried only doing it with S and T. At this point I'm not sure what the problem is.

Vertex Shader + fragment + Buffers: (It's not that long)

https://ideone.com/5U39M3

I'm not really sure what it could be at this point. I thought my texture wasn't getting it's attributes applied correctly, but it is. Then i thought it was just my wrapping method, but all methods lead to the same result.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that your UV coordinates for vertices are incorrect or used incorrectly.

Comment: I calculate them by clamping the x,y vertices position to 0-1 by doing UV = vec2((Position.x + 1.0) / 2.0 ), (Position.y + 1.0) / 2.0); so they should be right.

Comment: Nope. You don't take Z into account.

Comment: I'm using the same texture on all sides, so I didn't think I needed the z coordinator. Glsl won't let me pass in a texture(sampler2DTexture, textureCoords);  sampler2D needs a vec2 as Texpositions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that texture coordinates are incorrect. Instead of computing them you can try to specify them manually. (I think there is no way of computing texture coordinate for a point based only on it's position.)

Answer (score -1):

So turns out it was a problem with my UV coordinates.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem with the UV coordinates was? It's always nice to see an example so when I make the exact same mistake, I can see the solution!

Comment: I wasn't clamping the values properly. It's just copied the UV's online for a cube and it works fine now. I just wanted to create a function that would do it, instead of me having to write them all out.

Comment: @OmarMartinez Could you edit your answer and put that in?